How to Exactly Downsize Font outside Resizebox Based on Font Size inside Resizebox?
The following minimal working example resizeboxes a long tabular to textwidth, but the caption and sentences above the tabular are not downsized accordingly. I wonder whether there is a way to exactly downsize these caption and sentences referencing the font size inside the resizebox, instead of the naïve smalls below. Thanks for your help!
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

% How could one exactly downsize this caption?
\caption{\small This is a caption.}

% How could one exactly downsize these sentences?
{\small This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6.\par}

% based on the font size inside this resizebox
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\subcaptionbox{This is a subcaption.}{
\begin{tabular}{*{12}c}\hline
1.1111&2.2222&3.3333&4.4444&5.5555&6.6666&
7.7777&8.8888&9.9999&0.0000&1.1111&2.2222\\
1.1111&2.2222&3.3333&4.4444&5.5555&6.6666&
7.7777&8.8888&9.9999&0.0000&1.1111&2.2222\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Scaling elements which contain text is almost never a good idea. Choose a suitable font size instead.

Something like this is a bad idea as well: \caption{\small This is a caption.} configure your captions to be in that font size globally instead. Fx using the caption package.

It's simple: never resize your tables with \resizebox.

Sorry, but there are a few bad ideas in your example:

Scaling tables is bad, because you have no control whatsoever on the final result.

Even if you reduce the font size in a table to fit, the caption should be as in all other captions.

Font changing commands inside \caption should never be used.


I'm not contrary to scaling the font in the subcaption, though.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{This is a caption.}

\captionsetup[subtable]{font=footnotesize}
\subcaptionbox{This is a subcaption.}{%
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{12}c}
  \toprule
  1.1111 & 2.2222 & 3.3333 & 4.4444 & 5.5555 & 6.6666 &
    7.7777 & 8.8888 & 9.9999 & 0.0000 & 1.1111 & 2.2222 \\
  1.1111 & 2.2222 & 3.3333 & 4.4444 & 5.5555 & 6.6666 &
    7.7777 & 8.8888 & 9.9999 & 0.0000 & 1.1111 & 2.2222 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}


